# System Requirement for Android Studio and Eclipse

Tags: system

I am student, Now I am using Lenevo Laptop (i3 5 gen processor and 4 gb ram and shareable graphics) can I work with Andriod studio and Eclipse by this system ?

Comment: you can young boy ;)

Comment: ADT emulator are very RAM and CPU "hungry", but your system is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Better Configuration always gives you better performance. Eclipse you can run in your system. But when talking about Andriod studio for making apps then your system configuration not enough for performance. I am using think pad i5, 5th gen and 4gb ram, here  Andriod studio runs good but still there have some performance issues. So, best chose i5 or i7 with 8gb ram it will good for work and performance with  Andriod studio.